# How to store data in PowerPoint shape?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, vsto, metadata, office-interop

I'm developing PowerPoint Add-in using office interop in VSTO (C#), I want to store some data in the shapes.
How can I do it?
P.S: I found some docs about metadata but I didn't find a way to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small amounts of data, Tags may do the trick. Here is Microsoft's page about the Tag object: [Tags object (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.tags)

For larger amounts of data a custom XML part may work. [Custom XML parts overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/custom-xml-parts-overview?view=vs-2019)